# Using default method raises AbstractMethorError in Android release build

Tags: java, android, java-8, textwatcher, default-method

I have an interface that inherits from Android's `TextWatcher` to only implement `afterTextChanged` method. I have enabled Java 8 support in my project, and added source and target compatibility options in `build.gradle` file, but even though it works flawless in debug builds, it fails in release builds on every device I tested. I first noticed it in Play Console's pre-launch report, and tested again with the Firebase's Test Lab, still every device throw `AbstractMethodError` followed by a crash.

Here's my `AfterTextChangedListener`:

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

public interface AfterTextChangedListener extends TextWatcher {
    @Override
    default void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    default void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s);
}
```

Here's the portion of the code that uses this interface:

```
mSomeEditText.addTextChangedListener((AfterTextChangedListener) editable -> {
    // Logic using 'editable'.
});
```

Here's the Logcat output for the crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.package.name, PID: 4096
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.text.TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int)"
    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:9704)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5615)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5571)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:122)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5528)
    at i.a.a.f.c.d1.b(Unknown Source:25)
    at i.a.a.f.c.d1.b(Unknown Source:105)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.g(Unknown Source:11)
    at androidx.fragment.app.s.a(Unknown Source:35)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.a(Unknown Source:240)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.j(Unknown Source:2)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.i(Unknown Source:58)
    at androidx.fragment.app.a.e(Unknown Source:171)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.a(Unknown Source:38)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.b(Unknown Source:120)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.c(Unknown Source:84)
    at androidx.fragment.app.m.b(Unknown Source:31)
    at androidx.fragment.app.a.c(Unknown Source:6)
    at androidx.fragment.app.q.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at c.u.a.b.c(Unknown Source:385)
    at c.u.a.b.e(Unknown Source:2)
    at c.u.a.b.onMeasure(Unknown Source:191)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.b.a(Unknown Source:93)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source:275)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source:264)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source:156)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23181)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2727)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1580)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1864)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7208)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1004)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:816)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:751)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
   Force finishing activity my.package.name/.ui.activities.MainActivity
```

I don't have any idea why this happens especially considering Android supports default methods in interfaces.

[image: Default and static interface methods: Any]

Here's my module-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // keystore credentials
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 66
        versionName "2020.2b1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // Material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'

    // Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.3'

    // SafeRoom
    implementation "com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.1.3"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    //implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    //    transitive = true
    //}
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    // implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'

    // RoundedImageView
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20190722'

    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'

    // LeakCanary
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

sonarqube {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            // Some properties for sonarqube
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my project-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1' 
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7.1"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any idea why this happens, and how it can be solved?

Comment: Did you try changing default to public?
`default void beforeTextChanged` -> `public void beforeTextChanged`

Comment: Like `public default void`? No, I haven't, Android Studio says it's redundant, but will try. What does it do?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, and as expected, no luck.

Comment: Also, I am wondering why you creating a brand new interface when you don't have any new functions. You can use TextWatcher directly in your code, without the need of creating a brand new interface. New interface require when you are planning to extend it by adding new methods etc.

Comment: I created a new interface because I don't want to write unused methods `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` in `TextWatcher`, if I use it, code becomes bloated with empty implementations.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this -

```
public interface AfterTextChangedListener extends TextWatcher {
    @Override
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s);

    @Override
    void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after);

    @Override
    void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count);
}
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: It is exactly same as `TextWatcher`. But I want to discard unused methods `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged`, so I created a new interface.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that it be an interface? I would just use an abstract class for this.

```java
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

public abstract class AfterTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s);
}
```